# Sleepwatcher on OS X 10.11 not executing script on wake

Tags: python, macos, unix, terminal, macports

In installed Sleepwatcher 2.2 on OS X 10.11 and launching it via LaunchD as an agent.

It launches okay and shows up in the activity monitor.

However, I want it to fire off a python script when the computer wakes up.

My installation commands are as follows.

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/share/man/man8
sudo cp ~/Desktop/sleepwatcher_2.2/sleepwatcher /usr/local/sbin
sudo cp ~/Desktop/sleepwatcher_2.2/sleepwatcher.8 /usr/local/share/man/man8
sudo cp ~/Desktop/sleepwatcher_2.2/sleepwatcher/config/rc.sleep /etc
sudo cp ~/Desktop/sleepwatcher_2.2/sleepwatcher/config/rc.wakeup /etc
sudo cp ~/Desktop/sleepwatcher_2.2/sleepwatcher/config/de.bernhard-baehr.sleepwatcher-20compatibility-localuser.plist /Library/LaunchAgents

chmod +x /etc/rc.sleep
chmod +x /etc/rc.wakeup
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/test.py
```

My rc.wakeup file is as follows.

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/test.py
```

When executing Sleepwatcher at the terimnal window by typing in the following, it seems to work.

```
/usr/local/sbin/sleepwatcher --verbose --wakeup /usr/local/bin/test.py
```

However, when trying to run it as a start-up item under LaunchD, it does not seem to work execute my python script.

I have search all over and cannot figure out why it is not working when being launched in LaunchD.

Has anybody ran into this type of problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, I put in the command as chmod +x /etc/rc.sleep.  I am not sure why there was an extra space up above.

Comment: You seem to be missing the registration of the plist, which is needed to start `sleepwatcher` running, and to actually invoke the `/etc/rc.sleep` and `/etc/rc.wake` scripts when the sleep and wake events occur.

Comment: Hi Petesh, instead of doing a launchctl load  /Library/LaunchAgents/de.bernhard-baehr.sleepwatcher-20compatibility-localuser.plist, I rebooted the server.  This should also pick it up which it does.  Do you know if there are any logs that are left behind so that I can see what potentially threw an error either during load or during execution of the script during the wake event?

Comment: It turns out that there was nothing wrong with the above and the problem was in one of the files that was used.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered similar problems so I took a different approach using another open source tool called [Hammerspoon](http://www.hammerspoon.org/). It can provide for automation of bunch of things on MacOS including sleep/wake events. It's quite simple to replicate sleepwatcher's functionality by adding the following to Hammerspoon's `~/.hammerspoon/init.lua` (or create a 'spoon') script that triggers when the machine wakes or sleeps and calls the corresponding wake and sleep scripts (in e.g. `/Users/username/scripts` - ensure *`username`* is changed) from sleepwatcher:

```
function caffeinateWatcher(eventType)
    if (eventType == hs.caffeinate.watcher.systemWillSleep or
            eventType == hs.caffeinate.watcher.systemWillPowerOff) then
            print ("WillSleep...")
            -- Execute sleep script
            hs.task.new("/Users/username/scripts/rc.sleep", nil):start()
    elseif (eventType == hs.caffeinate.watcher.systemDidWake) then
            print ("Woken...")
            -- Execute wake script
            hs.task.new("/Users/username/scripts/rc.wake", nil):start()
    end
end

sleepWatcher = hs.caffeinate.watcher.new(caffeinateWatcher)
sleepWatcher:start()
```

Note if you want Hammerspoon to launch the shell scripts you need to ensure they start with the standard bash shell header `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: I am using your example for running some script on my company. Thanks. It hase been a bit difficult because, before enabling some log from the script, it was not clear what path he could or could not find. Thanks